How much does Micro-80 BASIC resemble Microsoft BASIC?
The first DIY Soviet home computer Micro-80 and its successor Radio-86RK had an implementation of BASIC available (albeit not in ROM, but as an loadable binary). A page from which the link is taken does not mention any provenance of the BASIC interpreter, it merely says "Есть бейсик "Микро-80" (цикл статей в журнале "Радио" в 1985 году). (There is BASIC "Micro-80" (a series of articles in the magazine "Radio" in 1985).)
The aforementioned series of articles - in particular, №1 contains the hex listing, №2-3 describe the language - does not mention where it came from. The authors neither mention its provenance or claim authorship, as if the code just fell from the sky.
I wonder how much commonality there is between the Micro-80 BASIC and the Microsoft BASIC for 8080. Was it a clean-room reimplementation, or most code was lifted from the Microsoft BASIC without attribution?
